# Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on null in class-db.php on line 15

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm working on a simple Content Management system and following a tutorial while customizing a bit of the code, I tried to find what i did wrong but couldn't find the problem.

Anyways here is my code for the a SQL connection. The fatal error occurs at `$result = $mysqli->query($query);`

```
<?php
    if (!class_exists('DB')){  
        class DB{
            public function __construct(){
                $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'mdatabase');

                if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
                    printf('Connection Failed %s/n',$mysqli->connect_error);
                    exit();
                }
                $propertyc->connection = $mysqli;
            }

            public function insert($query){
                $result = $mysqli->query($query);

                return $result;
            }

            public function select(){


            }
        }
    }

    $db = new DB;
?>
```

> Warning: Creating default object from empty value in C:\wamp\www\phptesting\includes\class-db.php on line 11
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: mysqli in C:\wamp\www\phptesting\includes\class-db.php on line 15
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on null in C:\wamp\www\phptesting\includes\class-db.php on line 15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your $mysqli variable is not a member of your class, so it is null inside the scope of your DB::insert() function. Try this:

```
<?php
    if (!class_exists('DB')){  
        class DB{
            public function __construct(){
                $this->mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'mdatabase');

                if ($this->mysqli->connect_errno) {
                    printf('Connection Failed %s/n',$this->mysqli->connect_error);
                    exit();
                }
                $propertyc->connection = $this->mysqli;
            }

            public function insert($query){
                $result = $this->mysqli->query($query);

                return $result;
            }

            public function select(){


            }

            protected $mysqli;
        }
    }

    $db = new DB;
?>
```

Also, your $propertyc variable is going to be null there, so $propertyc->connection isn't referring to anything.

Comment: Thanks, It worked. I removed the $propertyc->connection entirely. I realised it was useless there.